# jquery mobile page exits when clicking a button on the page

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a few pages defined like so:

```
   <div data-role="page" id="home">
      ...
   </div>

   <div data-role="page" id="settings">
      ...
      <button id="testSettingsButton">Test</button>
   </div>
```

The javascript looks like this:

```
    $(document).on("touchend", "#testSettingsButton", function(e) {

        try {
           // connect to remote database
           // an error is thrown and caught by the db library code
        } catch (err) {
           // not reached
        }
    });
```

When the user clicks the `Test` button, jquery mobile displays the `home` screen instead of staying on the `setting` screen.

Why is this happening?  How can I fix or debug this?

I'm using Jquery Mobile 1.4.5 on Cordova 4.1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple - I had forgotten to add `e.preventDefault();`
 to the method.  Adding this fixed the issue.

```
$(document).on("touchend", "#testSettingsButton", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
       // connect to remote database
       // an error is thrown and caught by the db library code
    } catch (err) {
       // not reached
    }
});
```